# Determine referenced type in static method

Tags: c#, c#-2.0

I think this may not be possible but if it is SO would know.

I have a abstract class that statically maintains instances of it's subclasses. I would like to implement a static `getInstance()` method in my base class that will get instance of the whichever class is referenced. So I need a way to tell which class was referenced in the static call.

I think the code will make this more clear:

```
abstract class Base
{
    private static List<Base> allInstances;
    public static List<Base> AllInstances
    {
        get {
            if(allInstances==null)
            {
                // Implementation not relevant and not included to avoid clutter
            }
            return allInstances;
        }
    }
    public static Base getInstance()
    {
        Type callingType = // This is what I am trying to fill in
        if(callingType == typeof(Base))
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Cannot get instance of Base class");
        return AllInstances.Find(i => i.GetType() == callingType);
    }
}


class A:Base { }
class B:Base { }
```

So if I called `A.getInstance()` my `callingType` variable would be `typeof(A)`. My primary goal is avoid having `Find` calls in my code to make it cleaner and more readable but I am also just curious if this is possible.

Comment: Do you mean for `getInstance` to be static? You are talking about it like it is static. If not, just use `this.GetType()`.

Comment: @mikez I did. I rewrote this to show what I'm talking about instead of using my actual code and didn't proofread it closely enough. I have fixed it.

Comment: I see. You can't without putting something into all the derived classes. This is because while you can invoke the method using `A.getInstance` and `B.getInstance` it compiles down to `Base.getInstance`.

Comment: @mikez I suspected that might be how the compiler would handle it but didn't know for certain. If you post that as an answer I will mark it.

Comment: You could do a terribly hacky trick and use a ```callingType = new StackTrace().GetFrame(1).GetMethod().ReflectedType;``` This would grab the stack frame of the caller and then extract the calling type. See also http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.memberinfo.reflectedtype.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expanding on my comments above, you can't really do what you are asking without putting code in all the derived classes. Part of the reason is that while you are able to access `A.getInstance()` and `B.getInstance()` they are both compiled down to the call `Base.getInstance()`. See the IL of simple method such as:

```
public static void CallGetInstance()
{
    var a = A.getInstance();
    var b = B.getInstance();
    Console.WriteLine(a == b);
}
```

is compiled to:

```
.method private hidebysig static
    void CallGetInstance () cil managed
{
    // Method begins at RVA 0x2054
    // Code size 24 (0x18)
    .maxstack 2
    .locals init (
        [0] class TestIL.Base a,
        [1] class TestIL.Base b
    )

    IL_0000: nop
    IL_0001: call class TestIL.Base TestIL.Base::getInstance()
    IL_0006: stloc.0
    IL_0007: call class TestIL.Base TestIL.Base::getInstance()
    IL_000c: stloc.1
    IL_000d: ldloc.0
    IL_000e: ldloc.1
    IL_000f: ceq
    IL_0011: call void [mscorlib]System.Console::WriteLine(bool)
    IL_0016: nop
    IL_0017: ret
} // end of method Program::CallGetInstance
```

Note that there is no mention of `A.getInstance` or `B.getInstance`. In fact, they do not exist in the IL. Tricks with `StackFrame` and such won't help because there is no method in the IL for `A.getInstance()` and `B.getInstance()`.

One workaround has been proposed by the other answers using a generic method that each derived class calls. This is about as simple as it is going to get.

Answer (score 1):

C# does not support virtual static methods.

One workaround would be to use a generic method for `GetInstance()`.  Instead of calling `A.GetInstance()`, callers would call `Base.GetInstance<A>()`.  The effect would be the same, however:

```
abstract class Base
{
...
  public static T getInstance<T>() where T : Base
  {
    Type callingType = typeof(T);
    // no need to check type; T will always be a type of or derived from Base
    return AllInstances.Find(i => i.GetType() == callingType) as T;
  }
}
```

While it would involve some boilerplate, you could then (if you choose) write convenience methods at the derived class level to obtain the same effect:

```
class A:Base 
{
    public static A getInstance() {return Base.getInstance<A>();}
}
class B:Base
{
    public static B getInstance() {return Base.getInstance<B>();}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Static methods are not inherited.  They are scoped to their class.  The way you have it written there is no "getInstance" method on A or B...only on Base.  So what you're trying to do isn't quite possible via your approach.

However, you can go with a generic method:

```
public static T GetInstance<T>() where T : Base {
    return (T)AllInstances.Find(i => i.GetType() == typeof(T));
}
```

Then you can just request instances of the types like this

```
var a = Base.GetInstance<A>();
var b = Base.GetInstance<B>();
```

Just as easy as

```
var a = A.getInstance();
var b = B.getInstance();
```

and because type T is limited to types that inherit base (via T : Base), you don't have to worry about other types of classes because this won't even compile:

```
var x = Base.GetInstance<SomeOtherRandomClass>();
```

Comment: The generic route is what I have done already, but I feel the actual answer to my question is that "`A.getInstance()` compiles the same as `Base.getInstance()`" which is why I wanted mike z to post that as an answer. This solution is a very good work around, not an answer to the question as asked.